# Pro.sparsebundele is in use. What is it?

Tags: backup

I got this message when trying to back up my Macbook Pro using time machine:

> The disc image MAMA'S’s MacBook Pro.sparsebundle is in use, try ejecting the disc image.

How do i do it?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution [here](http://blog.mc-thias.org/?title=time-machine-not-completing-backup-due-to-backup-disk-already-in-use&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1):

- Access the Airport Extreme using the AirPort Utility.
- Go to Manual Setup.
- Go to Disks.
- Click on Disconnect All Users…

At this stage, unplug or turn the external HD off, the plug it back or turn it on.